# MongoDB aggregation with multiple keys

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have looked at a few similar questions/answer, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597812/how-do-i-count-multiple-keys-in-the-same-mongodb-aggregation-group-query), but I can't solve my case.

I have a collection called `output` with documents of the form

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55e06ac3cd8a52ac141012f2"),
  "Date" : ISODate("2010-11-02T00:00:00Z"),
  "output" : 0,
  "region" : "Gotham"
}
```

These docs span multiple years and regions, I am trying to run an aggregate to get a breakdown of the total output, per region, per year. If I ignore the year I can get the first part using this

```js
output.aggregate(
    [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": { region: "$region"},
        "output": { "$sum": "$output" }
      }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {
      console.log(results);
      db.close();
    }
  );
```

which gives me

```sh
[ { _id: { region: 'Gotham' }, output: 2115715 },
  { _id: { region: 'London' }, output: 6799038 },
  { _id: { region: 'Tokyo' }, output: 8744809 }
```

but the output here is across several years, I want it broken down per year.

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```js
output.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project : {
        year: {
          $year: "$Date"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          region: "$region",
          year: ""$year
        },
        "output": { "$sum": "$output" }
      }
    }
  ],
  function(err,results) {
    console.log(results);
    db.close();
  }
);
```

this results in

```sh
[ { _id: { year: 2015 }, output: 0 },
  { _id: { year: 2014 }, output: 0 },
  { _id: { year: 2013 }, output: 0 },
  { _id: { year: 2012 }, output: 0 },
  { _id: { year: 2009 }, output: 0 },
  { _id: { year: 2008 }, output: 0 },
  { _id: { year: 2011 }, output: 0 },
  { _id: { year: 2010 }, output: 0 } ]
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"doesn't work"*?

Comment: is it possible that it fails because of the incorrect quoting of `$year`?

Comment: Updated question to show why it "doesn't work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core aggregation mistake.

When you use a pipeline operator like [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) then the **only** values that come through to the next pipeline stage are **only** those you specifiy explicitly. So your problem here is you reference fields in [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) that no longer exist in the document, because you "omitted them".

So after `$project` where you do not mention "region" then that field is no longer in the document to be processed in the next pipeline stage and that will cause problems.

The basic correction is "include them", but really, just use the operator directly in the `$group` as it is more efficient anyway:

```js
output.aggregate(
  [
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "region": "$region",
          "year": { "$year": "$Date" }
        },
        "output": { "$sum": "$output" }
      }
    }
  ],
  function(err,results) {
    console.log(results);
    db.close();
  }
);
```

And it's done

Think "unix pipe" like this:

```js
ps aux | grep mongo | grep something
```

And if you already filtered out "mongo" then unless you had "mongo something" in results then there is no longer any more "something" to match. This is the basic principle of "pipelines".

Comment: I asked the question in the hope you would answer it, after helping me yesterday. That works perfectly, thank you. I can't accept the answer as correct, however, because 5 minutes have yet to elapse

Comment: @robocode I wait with baited breath. Try and read and "digest" the "unix pipe" analogy I gave at the end. That really makes things clear when you think about it for a minute.

Comment: It really does, I hadn't considered the aggregation pipeline in that context, I guess I should have paid attention to the word pipeline!